# Crash on nil value - Love2D Lua

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm instantiating a ball and it works well, when I try to call `centerCoordinatesOn` it crashes.

```
Ball = Class{}

function Ball:init(skin)
    -- simple positional and dimensional variables
    self.width = 8
    self.height = 8

    -- these variables are for keeping track of our velocity on both the
    -- X and Y axis, since the ball can move in two dimensions
    self.dy = 0
    self.dx = 0

    -- this will effectively be the color of our ball, and we will index
    -- our table of Quads relating to the global block texture using this
    self.skin = skin

    self.needsStartup = true
end

function Ball:centerCoordinatesOn(x, y, width)
    print(x.." "..y.." "..width)--attempt to concatenate local 'width' (a nil value)
    self.x = x + (width / 2) - 4
    self.y = y - 8
end




self.ball = Ball()
self.ball.skin = math.random(7)    
self.ball.centerCoordinatesOn(1,1,1)--crash
```

If I remove the method and just call the content of it manually it works fine:

```
self.ball.x = 1 + (1 / 2) - 4
self.ball.y = 1 - 8
```

I've also tried renaming the variables, maybe they would conflict with the internal methods of the class width -> self.width, but the same things happed even if I call them a,b,c.

Comment: You forgot the `:` `self.ball.centerCoordinatesOn(1,1,1)` should be `self.ball:centerCoordinatesOn(1,1,1)`. the `:` passes `self` so a call without it should be `self.ball.centerCoordinatesOn(self.ball, 1, 1, 1)`

Comment: on right... I'm blind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `:` so you only have 3 params rather than the 4 expected by `centerCoordinatesOn`, when you call `self.ball.centerCoordinatesOn(1,1,1)`

This is because when you defined

```
Ball:centerCoordinatesOn(x, y, width)
```

an alternate way to write this definition is

```
Ball.centerCoordinatesOn(self, x, y, width)
```

with either definition `width` is the 4th param, which ends up `nil` with your current call.

So your call of `self.ball.centerCoordinatesOn(1,1,1)` should be:

```
self.ball:centerCoordinatesOn(1,1,1) --note the : after ball.
-- or --
self.ball.centerCoordinatesOn(self.ball, 1, 1, 1) --note first param is ball.
```